# Rendering Google Maps tiles in Leaflet (offline)

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I have Google Maps tiles on my computer in a folder. I want to use it offline in Leaflet. Actually, Leaflet use by a link to load the map like below:

```
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      }).addTo(map);
```

When I replace the local link on my computer `file:///D:/Map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` instead of `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`, the map does not load. But this link `file:///D:/Map/5/5/5.png` load correctly a tile on my browser and also it is same as this link on OpenStreetMap `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/5/5/5.png`
How can I do this?

Comment: Cross-post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826389/how-can-i-render-google-maps-tile-in-leaflet-offline

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons browser won't allow you to access files in an arbitrary folder on file system of your computer. Your tiles have to be in a subfolder of the folder where your map html file is.

For example, if your `map.html` file is in folder `D:/map`, then create subfolder `D:/map/tiles` and put your tiles there. Your tile layer creation should then look like this:

```
L.tileLayer('tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 19,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```